# What is the min and the max value of prediction length in Time-series Driverless AI

Tags: driverless-ai

I want to do some research to use *Driverless AI* in our project about energy.
We are interesting the Timeseries feature in *Driverless AI*.
But I don't know which the min/max value in the prediction length is.

In the document, they mentioned that the maximum value of prediction length is 39 week with sale forecast case study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prediction length (aka Horizon) is something the user of DAI has to specify, and is generally indicated by the test data the user provides. This means `39 weeks` is not the max value for any given use case, it is just the prediction length for the documentation's particular example.

from the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/time-series.html#user-configurable-options):

"Horizon (or prediction length) is the period that the test data spans for (for example, one day, one week, etc.). In other words it is the future period that the model can make predictions for."